# mysql deletion efficiency

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with large amount of data. The data need to be updated frequently: delete old data and add new data. I have two options

1. whenever there is an deletion event, I delete the entry immediately
2. I marked delete the entries and use an cron job to delete at unpeak time.

any efficiency difference between the two options?  or any better solution?

Comment: How large is large?  Thousands of rows, millions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Both delete and update can have triggers, this may affect performance (check if that's your case).
- Updating a row is usually faster than deleting (due to indexes etc.)

However, in deleting a single row in an operation, the performance impact shouldn't be that big. If your measurements show that the database spends significant time deleting rows, then your mark-and-sweep approach might help. The key word here is probably *measured* - unless the single deletes are significantly slower than updates, I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

You should use low_priority_updates - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_low_priority_updates. This will give higher priority to your selects than insert/delete/update operations. I used this in production and got a pretty decent speed improvement. The only problem I see with it is that you will lose more data in case of a crashing server.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL, deletes are simply marked for deletion internally, and when the CPU is (nearly) idle, MySQL then updates the indexes.

Still, if this is a problem, and you are deleting many rows, consider using DELETE QUICK. This tells InnoDB to not update the index, just leave it marked as deleted, so it can be reused.

To recover the unused index space, simply OPTIMIZE TABLE nightly.

In this case, there's no need to implement the functionality in your application that MySQL will do internally.